# Error on checkout - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this extremely strange error that only happens when people try to order. Guests come onto our site and add stuff to their cart. Then they proceed to go to the checkout. On checkout when they click proceed to paypal they get the following error: **"We were unable to process your order, please try again."**. However on reloading the page the error is gone when they try to recheckout. No plugins or themes are conflicting as I checked all of them.

I did some debugging and I noticed that the reason the error is thrown is because of the function: `wp_verify_nonce()` I did some further debugging and found out that during the first time the user tries to checkout the above function is called. And returns false because the nonce is different when compared to what is currently hashed. However on the second checkout the above function returns true because the nonce is correct. This means that for some reason my nonce is wrong the first time. Does anyone know why?

I'm getting this problem on the following function: 
`process_checkout()` When the following command is run:

```
if ( empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'woocommerce-process_checkout' )) {
    WC()->session->set( 'refresh_totals', true );
    throw new Exception( __( 'We were unable to process your order, please try again.', 'woocommerce' ) );
}
```

I tried my best to explain my issue but does anyone know why my nonce is wrong during checkout on the first time?

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't really with `wp_verify_nonce()` or the code you posted.

The way wp_nonce work is like a queue number, just like your processing number at the DMV.

My best guess on what's happening is an extra wp_nonce being created when people checkout and `wp_verify_nonce()` is receiving a different one from what's expected. There's no way for me to really identify where it's happening without looking at the code base.

If no custom code has been done for these parts then it really means there's a subtle plugin conflict with WooCommerce. It could be even a conflict with the theme.

Comment: Could possibly be my theme. Anything I should possibly be looking for? The only other plugin that we use that's related to woocomerce is woocheckout.

Comment: I'd try temporarily disable the plugin and see if the issue persists. Also I'd try to use a different theme temporarily to identify what's causing the issue.

Comment: Also note: it could be plugins that has nothing to deal with WooCommerce that's causing the issue, because `wp_nonce` are used for many purposes.

Comment: Is their something I should specifically look for in my theme. I use all popular plugins so I doubt its a plugin problem. And I do have an outdated theme.

Comment: Chances it's something has been added to functions.php. Also it could be an issue that can be fixed by updating the theme (don't forget to backup)

Comment: I updated my theme and i still got the error unfortunately.